# Distributing proprietary libraries

Tags: package, release, release-management

We have a platform along with some proprietary libraries(jars).

Our platform installer contains bunch of rpms and ansible playbooks.

I want to make these proprietary libraries available to our business partners, what is recommended way of doing so?

I am looking for scalable approach which will work with 100s of partners. Also it should be easily integratable with their build systems.

I am thinking about setting up a maven repository and create account for each partner. Is there any better way?

Answer (score 0):

Make a role to install your jars from a particular maven repository, then [fetch](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/galaxy.html#installing-multiple-roles-from-a-file) this role from an ansible galaxy repository(you can host your own, or make them public).